# Can Postman Variables be Passed Into Header?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to string a few **Postman** requests together for testing.

1. In the first request I set a global variable as a **test script**.

   ```
   tests['Status code is 200'] = (responseCode.code === 200);
     if (responseCode.code === 200) {
     try {
       let jwt = responseBody.replace(/"/g, '');
       pm.globals.set("jwt", jwt);
       console.log("Variable will be set to", jwt);
     }
     catch(e) {
       console.log(e);
     }
   }
   ```
2. In the second request I run a **pre-request script** as

   ```
   let jwt = pm.globals.get("jwt");
   ```

Then I try to pass it into the header

[image]

**Is it possible to pass a value into the header when running tests in the runner?**

When running tests in the **Runner** the second request fails due to having an invalid `jwt`, and the Postman docs only show examples passing variables into the URL.

Comment: What does the token response request look like? Not sure why you would need to replace any of that before setting the variable. You're also mixing the older test syntax with the newer set variable syntax - I would recommend refactoring what you have to use all the new `pm. *` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's covered in [postman auth](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization).

1. Authenticate to get the JWT(oken) - Token API request
2. Add the test in to capture the token

   var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

   postman.setEnvironmentVariable("jwt", jsonData.token);
3. Authorization > Type > Bearer Token
4. Token:  {{jwt}}
5. Setup your Environment
6. Select the Environment
7. Select Keep variable values from the Collection Runner dialog (if you are running it in command line)

Note: I'm using version 6.3.0.

[image: Bearer Token Auth]

Comment: I can get this to work when running from the main edit window using global variables, but fails when using the Runner.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Will you add to your answer that you must select an `Environment` and select `Keep variable values` from the Collection Runner dialog?

Comment: @Matthew I've added what you suggested to the answer. Please review and let me know if I missed anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you setup your environment and variables properly, maybe you haven't saved your environment? In my case, it was not recognizing the variable because of that. It would have an orange dot indicator if its not saved yet.